# How can parametrize jsonb_path_query in JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, jsonb

What would be the correct syntax to pass a paremeter into the jsonb_path_query using nativeQuery for the name_id property?

```java
@Query(value = "select jsonb_path_query(columns , '$.names[*] ? (@.name_id == :id && @.is_active == true)' ) -> 'name_id' as name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonb_path_query()` accepts an additional JSONB parameter that can contain variables as key/value pairs. The keys can be referenced using the `$` notation inside the JSON path:

```
jsonb_path_query(columns , '$.names[*] ? (@.name_id == $id && @.is_active == true)', '{"id": 42}')
```

The jsonb value can be passed as JDBC parameter:

```
"select jsonb_path_query(columns , '$.names[*] ? (@.name_id == $id && @.is_active == true)', cast(? as jsonb) ) -> 'name_id' as name"
```

Then you can pass a String parameter like `"{\"id\": 42}"` to the query.

I don't know JPA, in plain JDBC this would be used with a `PreparedStatement and` setString(1, "{"id": 42}")`